# How can i increment a variable with 4 in a for loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, increment, decrement

i have this for loop

`for (i = 0, j = N-1; i < j; ++i , --j )`

and i want to increment i with 4 not 1 and j decrement with 4 not 1.

Something like this, but i don't know the sintax:

```
for (i = 0, j = N-1; i < j; 4+=i , 4-=j )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the other way around: `i += 4`. This is shorthand for `i = i + 4`. Now you have written `4 += i` which means `4 = 4 + i` - which does not make sense of course.

Comment: Yes.  People seem to have trouble with +=, presumably because teachers don't explain it well.

Think of x += 1 as calling the += method on x.  The x.+= method adds the value of its argument to x.  So, x += 1 means with x.add_on(1), or "take x, and add the value 1 onto it".

Answer (score 1):

Try out:

for (i = 0, j = N-1; i < j; i+=4 , j-=4 )

The syntax is back-the-front, all you have to do is flip the 4+=i to i+=4, and 4-=j to j-=4

Comment: But, ++i is different from i++

Comment: @user2399087: only in specific contexts. For your loop counter use they are actually the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing:

`for (i = 0, j = N-1; i < j; 4+=i , 4-=j )`

Write this:

`for (i = 0, j = N-1; i < j; i+=4 , j-=4 )`

When you have the following code:

`i += 5;`

It basically means the same as:

`i = i + 5;`

And therefore 5 += i would mean the same as:

`5 = 5 + i;`

Which obviously doesn't make anny sense, because 5 is not a variable and therefore you cannot store a value into it.

Answer (score 0):

It is just syntactic sugar. just write `j=j-4`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`for (i=0,j=N-1;i<j;i+=4,j-=4)`

or (easier to understand first times)

`for (i=0,j=N-1;i<j;i=i+4,j=j-4)`

Instead of:

`for (i = 0, j = N-1; i < j; 4+=i , 4-=j )`

which would try to assign to 4 the value 4+i (4=4+i) and the same later (4=4-j):

> [Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment